# Creating hiking track based on Open Cycle Map (OCM) data?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, route

I need help.
In QGIS i’m trying to create GPX hiking route having Open Cycle Map as background layer. Like in brouter selecting points on map and to get route following routes on OSM.
Successfully imported OSM into QGIS but sometimes when i select parts of track it selects all branch and I need just part of that branch.

Comment: please EDIT your question and tell us what you want the hiking track use for: printing purposes? display a track on a website? get an GPX file with only the track? Transfer that track to a Garmin device for routing purposes? ... Why do you use QGIS to create that track? why not Garmin Basecamp, QMapShack, or http://brouter.de/brouter-web/ ?

Comment: http://brouter.de/brouter-web/ - is solution that can help.